# How to join or unionize a list of list elements (unknown length)

Tags: json, ansible

I'm parsing some values using `json_query`. After extracting the values I'm left with a list of elements which contain the list of values. My goal is to have a single list of un-nested values.
How can I achieve this?

E.g.:

```yaml
my_list: [ [1,2],[3,4],[5,6] ]
```

Should become

```yaml
my_list: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I can't use `my_list[0] | union([my_list[1]) | union(my_list[2])` because the my_list is dynamic.

Comment: Might be worth posting your original data structure along with you `json_query` filter, as there is also a way to flatten arrays in JMESPath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`flatten` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/ansible/builtin/flatten_filter.html).

Given:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ [ [1,2],[3,4],[5,6] ] | flatten(1) }}"
```

This yields the expected list:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  - 5
  - 6
```

---

And since you state that you are using `json_query`, note that there is also a way to flatten in JMESPath, called [flatten projection](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#flatten-projections), so you might bake this is your existing query.

As an example:

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ [ [1,2],[3,4],[5,6] ] | json_query('[]') }}"
```

Will also yield the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom plugin to handle Python-like jobs easily. To do this, create a folder named filter_plugins (make sure to use this reserved name) in the same folder as your playbook, and add your Python filter there.

```
$ tree
├── nested_list.yml
├── filter_plugins
│   └── nested_union.py
└── inventory
```

Make sure the filter contains the FilterModule class and filters method:

```
$ cat nested_union.py
class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'nested_union': self.nested_union,
        }

    def nested_union(self, nested_list):
        return [x for inner_list in nested_list for x in inner_list]
```

Call the new filter from your Ansible playbook:

```
---
- name: 
  hosts: local
  tasks:
    - name: Union merged lists
      vars: 
        my_list: [ [1,2],[3,4],[5,6] ]
      set_fact:
        new_list: "{{ my_list | nested_union }}"
...
```

Here is the inventory file, just for reference and to complete the example:

```
[local]
127.0.0.1 ansible_connection=local
```

And here is the result of the execution:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventory nested_list.yml -v

-- snip --

TASK [Union merged lists]
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {"ansible_facts": {"new_list": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}, "changed": false}
```

Comment: Although this is definitely a correct solution, that's a bit of an overkill to reinvent the `flatten` or `json_query` filters which are available out of the box as demonstrated in β.εηοιτ.βε answer.